# What can compiler error `Expected ')'` mean?

Tags: c++

What can the compiler error `Expected ')'` mean when generated on a line with a function call?

Comment: Umm, it means that the compiler expected to find a `)` at the specified location but didn't.  Not that hard to understand ;-)

Comment: It means the syntax is invalid. Since there are "an infinite number of ways" to generate such messages - of which the compiler is being quite clear about - such overgeneralized questions are not very useful.

Comment: Please show the line that generated the error. There are many typos and mistakes can cause this error to appear.

Comment: Please add testable example code

Comment: There are numerous ways to generate this error. Most, if not all of them involve a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it meant that I was missing a comma between parameters in a function call.